# Concatenated dynamic URL string stops working when redirect added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, dynamic-url

The following code works producing the right result - a clickable link in the correct format that goes to the right destination:

```
return "<a target=_blank href='https://www.betfair.com/exchange/#/football/event/" + fixture.eventId + "/market?marketId=" + fixture.marketId + "'>" + ('0' + now_utc.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + monthData).slice(-2) +  "<BR>" +  ' ' + ('0' + hoursData).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + now_utc.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + "</a>";
```

Here is the output:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.betfair.com/exchange/#/football/event/28934851/market?marketId=1.148981766">09-10<br> 18:45</a>
```

[image]

However, when I add redirect to the string it does not generate a clickable link, like so:

```
return "<a target=_blank href='http://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?pid=2614611&bid=9890&redirecturl=https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event/" + fixture.eventId + "/market?marketId=" + fixture.marketId + "'>" + ('0' + now_utc.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + monthData).slice(-2) + "<BR>" + ' ' + ('0' + hoursData).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + now_utc.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + "</a>";
```

Here is the output:

```
   <a target="_blank" href="http://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?pid=2614611&amp;bid=9890&amp;redirecturl=https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event/28934851/market?marketId=1.148981766">09-10<br> 18:45</a>
```

[image: No clickable link]

Do I need to escape some characters or is it the redirect that is breaking the generated URL?

Thank you

## EDIT:

Without redirect
[image]

With redirect
[image]

Comment: You probably need to URL encode the query string you are appending to the url: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Also consider using the browser tools to see what's actually being rendered by the browser (e.g. Chrome - F12 and then use the Element Inspector).

Comment: That's what the output shown is from.

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted your url:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?pid=2614611&amp;bid=9890&amp;redirecturl=https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event/28934851/market?marketId=1.148981766">09-10<br> 18:45</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And it renders fine:

[image]

With the link working (at least redirecting to betfair). That said the URL you've generated does look a bit odd, is your goal to render:

```html
    <a target="_blank" href="http://ads.betfair.com/redirect.aspx?pid=2614611&bid=9890&redirecturl=https://www.betfair.com/exchange/football/event/28934851/market?marketId=1.148981766">09-10<br> 18:45</a>
```

Comment: Yes I get the same thing. However, see above edits showing output screenshots complete with F12 reveal. URL is correct but <A> Text </A> is not showing for some reason. Thanks @Tom John

Comment: In this situation (not uncommon) I'd be inclined to build it up from something that you know works (e.g. that above) into your final implementation (or comment out) and then you'll spot the schoolboy error and kick yourself ;)

Comment: Haha yes thats what I have been trying to do before getting frustrated and reached out for help lol.

I tried the encode thingy but it would not produce any output in fact was preventing the datatable from rendering actually.

I'm not a C# programmer so it's a bit alien to me. Thanks mate.

Comment: It must be the datatables that are interfering with it somehow

Comment: Have you confirmed the url example you are rendering is correct? Maybe start there by "hard coding" the correct url (if it is not already) and seeing if that renders ok and work back from that.